# Creating a string in C of the form "1,2,3,4,5"

Tags: c, string

I'm having difficulty in generating a string of the form "1,2,3,4,5" to pass to a command line program.

Here's what I have tried:

```
int N=100;
char list[200];
for (i=0; i<2*N; i+=2) {
    char tmp;
    sprintf(tmp,'%d', i);
    strcpy(list[i], tmp);
    strcpy(list[i+1], ',');
}
```

**Edit:**
I don't feel this question is a duplicate as it is more to do with appending strings into a list and managing that memory and than literally just putting a comma between to integers.

Comment: Would try to send this code to the compiler? It will tell you syntactic errors. The general mistake is that you want to convert to a char string but you provide only a single char variable for both `tmp` and `list`.

Comment: `tmp` does not have space for more than 1 character. I think you want `char tmp[100]; /* space for up to 99 characters and a '\0' terminator */`

Comment: `tmp` and `list[i]` are not strings (they are characters). You cannot use them with string functions.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked answer. The linked answer is about writing two integers with a comma between them; the poster had problems to understand how `printf` works. This question is more interesting: It's about creating a string of `n` comma-separated numbers. It's probably more about memory handling for the string than about formatting.

Comment: This is just a code snippet for clarity. I agree, this is not a duplicate, can someone mark as such?

Comment: Can anyone help me towards finding a solution for formatting a list of comma seperated chars?

Comment: @pmg I only want to append one character (now I realise plus '/0') each time so would char tmp[2] be sufficient?

Comment: When i grows larger than 99, `sprintf(tmp, "%d", i);` will require `tmp` to have space for 4 characters!! (Also you need quotes to delimit the `%d`).

Comment: Yes! So obviously my indexing of the list array is not going to work here. What is the preferred method to append numbers with commas to the list then?

Comment: There's no "preferred method" because appending numbers-with-commas is just simple coding.. You might want to look at strcat. But basically, this code is broken in several ways that suggests you don't have a good grasp on what is going on. Walk  though it by hand and see where your indexes are. And pay attention to compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do what you need.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* CommaSeparatedListOfIntegers(const int N)
{
    if (N < 1)
        return NULL;
    char* result = malloc(1 + N*snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d,", N));
    char* p = result;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        p += sprintf(p, "%d,", i);
    *(p-1) = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Note that the function returns a heap allocated block of memory that the caller is responsible for clearing up.

Some points of note:

- We put a crude upper bound on the length of each number when converted to text. This does mean that we will over allocate the block of memory, but not by a massive amount. If that is a problem for you then you can code a more accurate length. That would involve looping from `1` to `N` and calling `snprintf` for each value to determine the required length.
- Note that we initially write out a comma after the final value, but then replace that with the null-terminator.

Comment: Why don't you just sprintf to `p`? What's the point of having the `num` buffer? Also, I'd use `calloc`.

Comment: @Dariusz Thank you. `sprintf` straight to `p` is much much better. As you might tell, I'm not fluent in C. I don't see the point in `calloc` here though. It just wastes time initializing the memory to zero only to be later assigned different values. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: right, didn't catch that! :) deleted the invalid comments

Comment: btw: an useful the trick for commas is `char* comma=""; for() { printf("%s%s", comma, realText); comma=",";}

Answer (score 2):

Let's forget about writing strings for the moment and write a function that just prints that list to the screen:

```
int range_print(int begin, int end, const char *sep)
{
    int len = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        if (i > begin) {
            len += printf("%s", sep);
        }
        len += printf("%d", i);
    }

    return len;    
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
range_print(1, 6, ", ");
printf("\n");
```

The function does not write a new-line character, so we have to do that. It prints all numbers and a custom separator before each number after the first. The separator can be any string, so this function also works if you want to separate your numbers with slashes or tabs.

The function has `printf` semantics, because it returns the number of characters written. (That value is often ignored, but it can come in handy, as we'll see soon.) We also make the upper bound exclusive, so that in order to print (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) you have tp pass `1` and `6` as bounds.

We'll now adapt this function so that it writes to a string. There are several ways to do that. Let's look at a way that works similar to `snprintf`: It should tabe a pre-allocated char buffer, a maximum length and it should return the number of characters written or, if the output doesn't fit, the number of characters that would have been written had the buffer been big enough.

```
int range(char *buf, int n, int begin, int end, const char *sep)
{
    int len = 0;
    int m, i;

    for (i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        m = snprintf(buf, n, "%s%d", 
            (i > begin) ? sep : "", i);
        len += m;
        buf += m;
        n -= m;
        if (n < 0) n = 0;
    }

    return len;    
}
```

This function is tricky because it has to keep track of the number of characters written and of the free buffer still available. It keeps printing after the buffer is full, which is a bit wasteful in terms of performace, but it is legal to call `snprintf` with a buffer size of zero, and that way we keep the semantics tidy.

You can call this function like this:

```
char buf[80];
range(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, 6, ", ");    
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

That means that we need to define a buffer that is large enough. If the range of numbers is large, the string will be truncated. We might therefore want a function that allocates a string for us that is long enough:

```
char *range_new(int begin, int end, const char *sep, int *plen)
{
    int len = (end - begin - 1) * strlen(sep) + 1;
    char *str;
    char *p;
    int i;

    for (i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        len += snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", i);
    }

    str = malloc(len);
    if (str == NULL) return NULL;

    p = str;
    for (i = begin; i < end; i++) {
        if (i > begin) p += sprintf(p, "%s", sep);
        p += sprintf(p, "%d", i);
    }

    if (plen) *plen = len - 1;
    return str;
}
```

This function needs two passes: in the first pass, we determine how much memory we need to store the list. Next, we allocate and fill the string. The function returns the allocated string, which the user has to `free` after use. Because the return value is already used, we lose the information on the string length. An additional argument, a pointer to `int`, may be given. If it is not `NULL`, the length will be stored.

This function can be called like this.

```
char *r;
int len;

r = range_new(1, 6, ", ", &len);
printf("%s (%d)\n", r, len);
free(r);
```

Note that the same can be achieved by calling our old `range` function twice:

```
char *r;
int len;

len = range(NULL, 0, 1, 6, ", ");
r = malloc(len + 1);
range(p, len + 1, 1, 6, ", ");
printf("%s (%d)\n", r, len);
free(r);
```

So, pick one. For short ranges, I recommend the simple `range` function with a fixed-size buffer.

Comment: A long post for a trivial problem, though a good one. In `range`: why not a `break` instead of `n=0`? And then `n<=0` instead of `n<0`. It would save computing time and be clearer.

Comment: @Dariusz: A trivial problem, but also a fun exercise. I agree on the ´break`; that's what I had first. But I thought I'd be stubborn and retain the `snprintf` semantics of "return the number of chars that would have been printed had the buffer been large enough".

Comment: @Dariusz Well, not really trivial. Asker could not solve it so from their perspective not trivial. And to get a really slick solution takes a bit of skilled polishing.

Comment: @Dariusz: No, but I set n to zero when it falls below. Without that, there's a segmentation violation waiting to happen, of course.

Comment: @MOehm I realized that and deleted my comment in the meantime. Your code is fine. Though ... well, there is something bad about it. It's not obvious. I had to spend a few minutes to fully understand what it is doing. And I didn't know why it was doing what it was doing. Make sure that you comment such cases appropriately, because if you or someone else visits this code after a month he won't know what is it doing and why.